# How do I create a sharepoint video gallery based on List data?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am a complete sharepoint novice but have been working with ASP.NET for a few years. Essentially the images in this gallery will change on a weekly basis, so they need to be derived from sharepoint list data. The list will contain a flag ShowImageInGallery, a link to the video and a link to the thumbnail image.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: TO be more specific, it is a video gallery with thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

You already have a thumbnail gallery as part of a regular site in SharePoint, no need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because I need it to link to videos.

Comment: Do it an normal but contain is in a Web Part. Then deploy the Web Part as a Feature.